# Schema.org for CAD files (dwg, 3ds)

Tags: schema.org, autocad, dwg

I'm finding the best category for a website which offers files like DWG or 3DS for download.
I have looked in this [article](https://ludwig.im/en/projects/html5-and-schema.org-seo-best-practices-for-microdata) the "DesignApplication" but in [Schema.org](http://www.schema.org) doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure what you need here... the DWG is not XML based, but a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

There are several to choose from, all are more specific types than http://schema.org/CreativeWork - and contain all the CreativeWork fields.

http://schema.org/MediaObject lets you specify the type of file and seems designed for multimedia files like sound or video.

If your files are really code snippets you can use http://schema.org/Code or http://schema.org/SoftwareApplication (designed for binaries) and http://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode (allows programming language to be specified).

For the moment I think all you are looking for can be found in http://schema.org/CreativeWork - if DesignApplication becomes part of the official schema later it would be as a type of CreativeWork, so altering the code would be very simple.

Your website itself would use http://schema.org/WebSite (or http://schema.org/WebPage) with the CAD files using the schema you choose, using more than one schema in a webpage is common.